# Run PHP code when user clicks link and pass variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I need to run a PHP code from external server when user clicks a link. Link can't lead directly to PHP file so I guess I need to use AJAX/jQuery to run the PHP? But how can I do it and how can I pass a variable to the link?

Something like this?

`<a href="runcode.html?id=' + ID + '">` and then runcode.html will have an AJAX/jQuery code that will send that variable to PHP?

Comment: you can not load content from another server using ajax call. but your question is not clear to me. perhaps you need iframe / JSONP solution if want to call script from another  server i.e. cross domain call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this in you page with link

Some text

in the same page put this somewhere on top

```
<script language='javascript'>
$(function(){
$('.myClass').click(function(){
var data1 = 'someString';
var data2 = 5;//some integer
var data3 = "<?php echo $somephpVariable?>";

$.ajax({

url : "phpfile.php (where you want to pass datas or run some php code)",
data: "d1="+data1+"&d2="+data2+"&d3="+data3,
type : "post",//can be get or post
success: function(){
        alert('success');//do something
    }

});
return false;
});
});

</script>
```

on the url mentioned in url: in ajax submission
you can fetch those datas passed
for examlple

```
<?php
$data1 =$_POST['d1'];
$data2 =$_POST['d2'];
$data3 =$_POST['d3'];
//now you can perform actions as you wish
?>
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an ajax request too. The basic idea is:

1. Send ajax request to runcode.html
2. Configure another AJAX to trigger from that page

Considering, this as the markup

```
<a id="link" href="runcode.html'">Test</a>
```

JS

```
$("#link").on("click", function() {
    $.get("runcode.html", { "id" : ID }, function(data) {
       //on success 
    });
    return false; //stop the navigation 
});
```