# Run PHP code on user click and pass variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am using the following answer I've gotten from another question,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    $.get("somepage.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">Click Me!</a>
```

I'm just wondering how I can pass a couple more variables from the page this code is on to the `somepage.php` (the page that I am calling).

Also, once that .php page is ran, how can I then use some of the data that it generates back on the page that I ran this code from (basically to update the user that it has been ran by updating a field possibly).

It'd be great if someone could at least tell me how I can pass php variables over to the other .php page.

By the way, I know there is a similar question here: [Run PHP code when user clicks link and pass variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241259/run-php-code-when-user-clicks-link-and-pass-variables)

That also has an answer, but I am trying to use the code that I provided, since it's very simplistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an ajax post call:

```
//Inside your function 
var someVar = <?php echo $variable ?>;
var anotherVar = <?php echo $newVar ?>;

$.post("somepage.php", {firstParam : someVar, secondParam : anotherVar}, function(data) {
    //this is your response data from serv
    console.log(data);
});
```

You ccan access that data you sent then:

```
$paramOne = $_POST['firstParam'];
$paramTwo = $_POST['secondParam'];
echo "some response";
```

And your `data` from above will be "some response". In a nutshell;

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite a newbie in Ajax/jQuery. The first snipped you provided would call the .php page and then the `firstParam : someVar` part would be the variable that I want to pass? Now, can I just add the php value there? I have a variable in php: `<?php echo $myVariable; ?> that I need to pass. I actually need to pass multiple variables. So how would I go about doing that?

Comment: and how would I use them in my "somepage.php"?

Comment: Why would you be passing php generated variables back to the serv, they're already there, and unless they've been changed somewhere else, shouldn't they already be what you need?

Comment: If I use something like include or require in my somepage.php file it will run the php code on the included file again, for me to use the variable. Would that be the only way of going about it?

Comment: I see, one second, updating answer.

Comment: Alright, I see that you can declare and assign variables, which I've copied over. Now, how do I get multiple parameters to send to the php page, and how do I retrieve them from that php page, as php variables.

Comment: Simple, I've updated the answer. Just add another key/val pair.

Comment: Now how do I exactly use this data on my somepage.php?

Comment: and I am assuming we'd want to add return false; at the end of the function so the link doesn't go anywhere?

Comment: Yes, if you're using empty links. On that `somepage.php`, simply catch the variables with `$_POST` and use them how you want, then echo your result back to use it.

Comment: So I don't need to prepare these variables at all? somepage.php will have access to them?

$_POST['firstParam']; 

No need to include or use javascript correct? I can just set these parameters as variables in PHP and then use them?

Comment: okay, this is working perfectly! Thank you so much. I just have one final question, how can I take information from the .php page that I just ran and use it in my main page, to show the updated results? It's just one variable that gets updated, I just need the main page to retrieve it and then show it.

Comment: @user27899 -- Echo back the variable you want to use at the end of the php script, then the callback from the `.post` function using the `data` variable will contain your PHP variable, in short.

Comment: I am echoing two variables at the end of my php script. Could you please show me how I can then use these values and update them automatically on my main .php page?

Comment: got it to work! I ended up just using a id and then using .html(data) to put all the data in that div. Worked out great! Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to php page using a POST.

here a example:

[Pass data from jQuery to PHP for an ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210025/pass-data-from-jquery-to-php-for-an-ajax-post)