# ajax a href onclick get php variable and execute php file

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, animation

Before I ask this question, I have already referred to the example of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241259/run-php-code-when-user-clicks-link-and-pass-variables?rq=1). However, it seems doesn't work. Without using ajax, I can get my post deleted but after implement ajax, the deleteAtc.php seems to be not working.

My delete page code (delete.php)

```
    <h4>Select an Article to Delete:</h4>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

        <span><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></span> <a href="#" id="link">Delete</a><br />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#link').click(function(){
                var id = <?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "deleteAtc.php",
                    data: "id"+id+,
                    sucess: function() {
                        $('#sucess').html(data);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
        <div id="success"></div><br />
    <?php } ?>
```

While my deleteAtc.php code:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();

        echo "Article deleted";
    }
}    
?>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to delete the record without redirect to `deleteAtc.php`, it will remove out the record and replace `Article Deleted`

<s>May I know where did I go wrong in ajax side?</s>

**Please refer below for updated question**

---

Based on the answer below, here is my updated code:

delete.php

```
<h4>Select an Article to Delete:</h4>

<div id="message"></div>

<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<span><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></span> 
<a href="#" class="link" data-artid="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">Delete</a><br />
<?php } ?>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.link').click(function(){
                var elem = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "deleteAtc.php",
                    data: "id="+elem.attr('data-artid'),
                    dataType:"json",  
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.success){
                               elem.hide();
                               $('#message').html(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

deleteAtc.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();

        //Also try to handle false conditions or failure
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>TRUE,'message'=>"Article deleted"));
    }
}    
?>
```

Somehow, if I delete two record at a time, only the first record echo the result, the second result deleted doesn't echo out the result.

Am wondering, possible to add jquery animation to .show the success message and .hide the record deleted?

Comment: Syntax error unexpected token `"id"+id+,`

Comment: change from `data: "id"+id` to `data: "id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"`

Comment: @Musa it didn't show this error, that's why make's me, figuring out what's go wrong, may I know what is the correct method to do for my desired output?

Comment: @Nouphal.M yes now it work, but it didn't echo out the result and hide the deleted record

Comment: `sucess: function() {` should probably be `success: function(data) {`, then `data` will contain the message from the server. On the line below it should be `#success` as well instead of `#sucess`

Comment: @TiiJ7 now it manage to echo out the result, but is it possible to hide the record that deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all IDs are not meant to be duplicated, use class selector instead. Also you could make use of custom data attributes to store the id of the article.

Try

```
<h4>Select an Article to Delete:</h4>

<div id="message"></div>

<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<span><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></span> 
<a href="#" class="link" data-artid="<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">Delete</a><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.link').click(function(){
                var elem = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "deleteAtc.php",
                    data: "id="+elem.attr('data-artid'),
                    dataType:"json",  
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.success){
                               elem.hide();
                               $('#message').html(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

And in server side

```
<?php 

session_start();

include_once('../includes/connection.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();

        //Also try to handle false conditions or failure
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>TRUE,'message'=>"Article deleted"));
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: your `json` part not working, I changed it to this code `echo json_encode("'success'=>TRUE,'message'=>'Article deleted'");` but somehow the success message didn't show and the record didn't hide. But the record got deleted

Comment: changed to your suggested code but the echo part and hide element seems not to be working

Comment: changed the code, but echo result and hide deleted record not working, seems to be script side? the delete record work but not script

Comment: There was a `c` missing on the `success` function, edited it. Typing error. but its not an excuse i know. it was `sucess`. Apologize for my ignorance. :)

Comment: thanks! answer voted and accepted. Just wondering why if I delete two at a time, it only echo once which is the first record, the second record it doesn't echo out. By the way can I implement, jquery-ui show and hide?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45021/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-nescafe)

Comment: you didn't response to me at the chatroom

Comment: i waited for you like half an hour there

Answer (score 0):

The above script won't work you have to change like below. You are repeating the same identifier function again and again. Keep the jquery script out of foreach loop. You have to add the class property with the article id.

```
<h4>Select an Article to Delete:</h4>

    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

        <span><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></span> <a href="#" id="link" class='<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>' >Delete</a><br />

        <div id="success"></div><br />
    <?php } ?>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#link').click(function(){
                var id = $(this).prop('class');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "deleteAtc.php",
                    data: "id="+id,
                    sucess: function() {
                        $('#sucess').html(data);
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create several links with `id="link"`. ID must be unique.

You have to write

```
id="link<? echo $article['article_id']; ?>"
```

as well as

```
$('#link<? echo $article["article_id"]; ?>').click(function() {...})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".delbutton").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);      
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this record? There is NO undo!"))
        {
            $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                url: "products/delete_record.php",
                data: info,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        location.reload('');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
                $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");      
        }
        return false;
        //location.reload();
    });
});
</script>
```